# Pidgin building from source ./configure error

Tags: unix, makefile, configure, pidgin

I am trying to build Pidgin from the source code, and have been following the directions [here](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Installing%20Pidgin#IhavethesourcehowdoIbuildthisthing). When trying to run `./configure`, I get these errors:

```
./configure: line 2672: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 2682: config.log: Permission denied
```

I'm not sure what to do from here in order to fix the error. I don't seem to have a config.log in the directory and Google searches and pidgin irc has been less than fruitful.

Comment: As cmdprompt indicates this is almost certainly a permissions problem on the files you extracted from the source tarball (or files you created by running the autotools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to check is your permissions. Do you own the directory you are working in? (you didn't sudo the tar command did you?)

Comment: Wow thanks it did belong to root. I do not feel like a smart man